# LinqPad issues with hard coded values

Tags: linq, linqpad

Been playing around with LinqPad (really loving it btw) and found out that it won't like it if I hardcoded values into my Select query like so :

```
from id in TEST 
select new 
   {
       Id = 0
   }
```

That shows up (in the SQL tab) as:

```
SELECT NULL 
FROM TEST t0
```

I thought LinqPad would generate something along the lines of

```
SELECT 0 AS Id
FROM TEST t0
```

Is there a way to get that behavior in LinqPad?

Comment: I would imagine it is because in the select clause it puts all the data it needs from the table. Since it needs one it puts null. My question is why *would* it send constant values to the database just to have them sent back. In this case its just a four byte integer but if you were returning a thousand rows of data that would be 4000 bytes. If instead it were a long string then it would be more. This kind of optimisation just minimizes network traffic. Why do you want it to put those details in the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked on http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/312/how-to-make-linqpad-sql-window-return-constants where Joe Albahari (the author of LinqPad) replied

> First, this is a function of the ORM that you're using - in this case,
>   LINQ to SQL, not LINQPad. As it happens, though, LINQ to SQL is doing
>   the right thing here.
>
> LINQ to SQL tries to satisfy your query in the most efficient way
>   possible. So if you ask for a constant, it figures it can supply that
>   constant without round-tripping to a server and back. Unless there's a
>   reason why it needs to include that constant in the query to make it
>   valid, it will leave it out.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Wont get into details but I needed to return constants in one of my selects and union it with another select that uses columns. This works during runtime so I would've expected it to work in LinqPad too. Oh well....

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ query you gave just says an anonymous object with Id set to 0 for each record in test.  Sending the constant to the SQL server just to have it return it again would/could just make the query results larger.  It's one of LINQ's optimizations.  If LINQ was really good, it would have just generated a count, and returned that many 0's, but the optimizer isn't quite that good yet, so it returns rows that contain null instead.

LinqPad's results should show one anonymous record with the Id property set to 0 for each record in test, just like you requested it to.  A more optimized query would be:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,TEST.Count()).Select(r=>new {Id=0})
```

in my test environment with a table containing ~10,000 rows executes in 0.035 seconds, while your original version executes in 0.070 seconds, and the difference grows as the row counts increase.

Comment: Thats fine, but I was just wondering why LinqPad treats it as SELECT NULL as opposed to SELECT 0 AS id

Comment: It isn't just that it uses null instead of 0, but it removes every column that does not access the database from the select statement. If your statement was `select new { id.Field1, id.Field2, id = 1, Deleted = false, Date = DateTime.Now}` you would get something like `Select Field1, Field2 from test`. In your case you have not actually included any columns, but as `select from test` isn't valid, it uses `select null from test`.